# Vuejs webpack prefix static assets

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, webpack-2, vuetify.js, vue-loader

Hello I have made a Vuetify app using `vue-cli` and `vue init vuetifyjs/webpack-advanced` the resulting code is this https://github.com/vuetifyjs/webpack-advanced/tree/master/template

The problem I have is that my production app isn't in the root of the server and it is a subpath in `www.example.com/foo`. When I run `npm run build` all my static assets like images and fonts are referenced like `/static/images/example.png`, so the server doesn't find them as they are being looked in `www.example.com/static/images/example.png` instead of `www.example.com/foo/static/images/example.png`

If I change `config/index.js` and set `assetsPublicPath: '/foo'` and change all my references from `/static/...` to `/foo/static/...` then my production server finds all my static assets but then my dev server using `npm run dev` can't find them as they are being referenced as `localhost:8080/foo/static/images/example.png` but they seem to be at  `localhost:8080/static/images/example.png` for some reason.

My ideal solution would be just to keep the references as /static and tell webpack or vueloader somehow that on `npm run build` it should prepend /foo to all of my assets. If that is impossible at least I would like to know a way to make my dev and production enviroments to work with the same code even though it implies to prepend manually /foo to my static assets urls

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The template has this ability built-in, just set the different values in `config/dev.env.js` and `config/prod.env.js` and they'll override the base ones depending on the environment.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more? As I mentioned my problem isn't setting a different assetsPublicPath for dev or prod, the problem is that I have to change manually all my static urls each time I want to make a build

Comment: How are you referring to the images in your components? The template uses url-loader, which will copy the images to the public folder and set the url accordingly.

Comment: <img src='/static/logo.png' />